# how to get the old value of an object in map.putAll()?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

```
HashMap map= new HashMap(); 
System.out.println(map.put(101,"john"));//null 
System.out.println(map.put(101,"abhraham"));//john
```

If I give the key which is existing it replaces the value and returns the old value.

But if I use putAll how can I get the oldvalues?

```
HashMap map2=new HashMap();
map2.put(101,"Lincoln");
System.out.println(map.putAll(map2));//runtime exception
```

If I want the old value that has been replaced what I should use in map?

leave the printing part if i want the old value what i must do.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format your code better in future. Note that your second snippet will only give a runtime exception if you ignore the *compile-time* failure, because `putAll` returns `void`. Don't try to run code that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace them one at a time using `Map.put()`, which will return the old value:

```
HashMap oldValues = new HashMap();
map2.forEach((key, value) -> {
    oldValues.put(key, map.put(key, value));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HashMap.putAll()` method has a void return type, which is why you get the exception. You must call the `HashMap.put()` method for each element of the `map2` variable and then either print them individually or put them in another map and then print it's content (or do what you want with them).